# File in C, read some integers and put in array

Tags: c, file

In C, if i want to read a list of integers, but the problem is this.
I must read the first two number and this two number are a dimension for my array.
Now, my doubt is, i read this two number, but my file will point to next int?

Example: (there are 3 array of integres in this file)

```
3 4
11 -1 1 -12
0 -2 12 2
-8 4 4 7
2 3
8 -8 1
6 -3 -3
3 2
1 1
3 4
-1 8
```

first array is:

```
DIMENSION [3][4]
11 -1 1 -12
 0 -2 12 2
-8  4 4  7
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Starting from the "doubt".

Comment: Can you demonstrate that you can read each number in this file, one at a time, and print to console? If you can do this, solving the rest of your problem is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

After you open a file to read, each call to read moves the cursor, meaning after you have read the first line which contains the dimensions, your cursor will be at the start of the secind line.

To read the the arrays after getting the dimensions, I would use `malloc` to create the two dimensional array for the values.

After each block of array you can call `free` and `malloc` or `realloc` to read the next one.